# Let to do/ let do/ to let to do/ to let do

Tags: infinitives, phrase-choice, bare-infinitives

European customs officers are not easy to corrupt, so you have hardly any chances to get them **__** something illegal across the border.
**A. let you to take**
**B. let you take**
**C. to let you to take**
**D. to let you take**

What is the right answer to the task? I think it should be C. or D. , since we have to use to +infinitive after "get". For me D. sounds a bit more natural. So is it D. ? If so, which rule are we using to determine whether the right answer is C. or D.? Is it the rule that after let we use bare infinitive (infinitive without to) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the same way as

> get somebody to do something

requires "to",

> let somebody do something

requires the bare infinitive without "to".

The "rule" is what I have said just above: it is an idiosyncratic property of the verb "let", that cannot be predicted but just has to be learnt.